Chebyshev approximation via iterated weighted least squares fits
I have the task of finding a Chebyshev approximation for a time-series; I want to check different types of functions, e.g. polynomials, rational functions, harmonics, etc.
I know that the Remez algorithm solves that problem for polynomials but its application to other functions has its own challenges which incurs a lot of implementation overhead for testing different function classes; that contrasts weighted least squares approximation, whose application to various function classes is straight forward.
That led me to the
Questions:


can Chebyshev approximations be calculated by iteratively calculating weighted least squares approximations by giving values with higher approximation error a higher weight in the next iteration?
is there an optimal algorithm for calculating the weights for the next iteration from the errors of the current iteration when "optimal" means yielding the fastest rate of convergence?


This question is primarily aimed at linear least squares, i.e. $\min\limits_{\alpha_i}\max\limits_{x_j}\left|y(x_j)-\sum\alpha_if_i(x_j)\right|$
but answers related to other interpretations are also appreciated.
To put some flesh to the bones in reply to fedja's request for a more specific statement of the problem:

the concrete problem I have is to "reconstruct" a smooth function from almost regularly spaced samples, whose values were rounded to integer values; therefore least squares approximation isn't acceptable because individual errors may become arbitrarily large, but I know that they must not exceed $0.5$ in the problem at hand.
The functions I intend to use for approximation are linear combinations of damped harmonics, $f_{ij}(x):=e^{a_ix}\sin(b_jx)$ with fixed values for the $a_i$ and the $b_j$.
The task is then to determine the set of $\lbrace c_{ij}$ factors for the function's linear combination that yields the best Chebyshev approximation.
I'm aware that it is not guaranteed that the error bounds may still be violated for a specific set of functions, but that can be overcome by  extending that set.
It may be assumed that the least squares approximation has a high number of sign-changes in the error, so that balancing the magnitude of positive and negative errors should be possible.


Can you be more specific? Are you always approximating by elements in a finite-dimensional linear space of continuous functions, or something else? I see you mentioning rational approximation, but I do not understand how least squares can be efficiently applied to this case (provided we talk about the usual class of rational functions with fixed degrees of numerator and denominator). It looks like an interesting question, but I would like to see it more precisely posed before thinking of it :-)

@fedja as my specific problem in the purest sense is "only" to determine a finite set of parameters for which the evaluation of the approximating functions yield minimal maximal error for their evaluation at a discrete set of arguments, I only demand continuity at these arguments. Of course "secondary" concerns like overall continuity and smoothness constraints play an important role. Please feel free to make assumptions about the function space as appropriate for a theoretical discussion of the proposed idea.

What I mean is the following: Suppose you want to approximate just at 2 points and your set of admissible pairs of values (parameterized in some fancy way) is the union of $y_1+2y_2\le 0$ and $2y_1+y_2\le 0$ (the "outer" angle with the vertex at the origin avoiding the first quadrant). Then the best approximatoin for $(1,1)$ is $(0,0)$, but you will never be able to touch this point by an ellipse with center $(1,1)$ and axes parallel to coordinate lines. So you need to compromise from your super-general setting to something that is both useful for you and still theoretically feasible.

I don't quite understand the argument; a circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$ is an ellipse that when centered at $(1,1)$ has distance $0$ to $(0,0)$, or do you by "touching" mean the existence of a common tangent in a common point? Could you please formulate the least squares approximation problem and also the Chebyshev approximation problem for your example and explain why the optimal solution to the latter problem can't be approximated arbitrarily well by solutions to the weighted versions of the least squares problem?

I mean that the least square approximation will be always on the sides of the angle and never at the vertex no matter what weights you take. If you choose equal weights, you'll end up with 2 equally good points neither of which is what you want. Just draw the picture. In general, the LS just expands the ellipse until it touches the admissible (realizable by your parametric functions) set and Chebyshev expands a cube. The point is that the cube can touch at a point which is not accessible by an ellipse (i.e., the ellipse will always touch earlier somewhere far away).

The Chebyshev problem in my setting: $\max(|y_1-1|,|y_2-1|)\to \min$. The general LS problem: $w_1(y_1-1)^2+w_2(y_2-1)^2\to\min$. The latter can never give the same result as the former. Is it clear now what I'm saying?

yes, indeed now it is clear to me; thanks for clarifying.

In principle I have some idea that might work when the task is feasible (say, in the linear subspace approximation problem), but I don't know what sort of problems you are really aiming at, so give me a few samples to try it on and, if it is a non-linear setting, explain clearly how you are going to get the LS minimizer. Then I'll play with it a bit and report the results :-)

@fedja I have added a more detailed descriptionof my specific problem; I hope it helps

OK, got it. Now the technical question: how many $f$'s and how many sample points do you typically have?

The number of points that are subject to the approximation are about 100 to 500 and the number functions is about 5, which should suffice because the series looks like a fairly smooth function with added high frequency noise of small amplitude and then subjected to truncation to integer values.

OK, I guess I have a good algorithm for you. I just want the final check. Tell me some linear combination of exponentially damped sign functions and the interval on which you want to recover them from rounding. I just want to make sure that the size of everything is realistic (I played with 500 points on [0,1] and the space spanned by some 7 weird functions, so I want to check that everything scales fine to your setup).

@fedja just take $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$ for the exponential's coefficients and $\lbrace 0,\pi,2\pi\sqrt{2}\rbrace$ for the sine's coeffients; that should suffice for demonstrational purposes

On what interval? With what size coefficients? It all matters for numeric stability and such...

@fedja let the arguments be regularly spaced in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, the y-values in $[-1,1]$

OK, 9 functions (all combinations of frequencies and exponents, coefficients of size 1, interval $[-pi,pi]$, 500 regularly spaced points, rounding and trying to recover. If something is wrong, let me know. If everything is right, wait 20 minutes for the report and then, if successful, an hour or two for posting

Should now be in the chat (want to move there?), but on 100 random (in terms of coefficients $c_{ij}$) runs the recovery was successful and took on average 30 iterations of the main loop, each iteration testing from 1 to 9 weights depending on your luck. I write in Asymptote. Is it OK for you if I post the Asymptore code or you want me to convert to C++? Sorry for the delay: got distracted with some other things in the process :-)

I tried several techniques and, as usual, the simplest one turn out to work the best, so I'm posting it here.
Abstractly, we just want to find the point $x$ in an affine $m$-dimensional space $E$ of $\mathbb R^n$ ($n\approx 500, m\approx 10$, if I interpreted your "five functions" remark right) with the least $\ell^\infty$ norm $\|x\|_\infty$. In other words, we start expanding the cube from the origin until it touches $E$. What we have is an oracle (your implementation of weighted least squares) that for every weight $w$ returns the point $x(w)$ in $E$ of the least $\ell^2(w)$ norm.
WARNING: For my algorithm to work, this oracle should be decent, i.e., it should return the point sufficiently close to the true minimizer. If the least square problem is nearly singular and the oracle returns some garbage instead of the good approximation to the true solution occasionally, it may cause the unpredictable behavior of my algorithm as well. So if you want to go to larger $m$, I suggest that you think really hard about how to implement LS in a numerically stable way.
If we had $m=n-1$ (the affine hyperplane case), the task would be trivial. Take some initial weight $w_0$ (say, uniform) and ask the oracle for $x(w_0)$. Then you'll know the point $x(w_0)$ on the ellipsoid at which it is tangent to $E$. But then you know $E$! So, all you need is to formulate the new oracle query such that the output would be the point with all coordinates equal in absolute value. The elementary geometric considerations show that it happens for the weight $w[k]=w_0[k]|x(w_0)[k]|$. You switch to that weight and, voila, the oracle outputs the Chebysev approximation.
The problem is that our $m\ll n$. The key point is that for the $\ell^\infty$ approximation only some $m+1$ coordinates really matter (the alternance theorem; note, however, that you don't have a Chebyshev system, so the alternance does not have to be classical, i.e., when you go from left to right, the signs do not need to flip every time, you can even get multiplicity 2 alternance points). The only issue is that we don't know which ones.
So, we start with approximately equally spaced $m+1$ points on the interval when we are talking about smooth functions (theoretically we can start with anything, but for smooth functions starting with close points may cause numerical stability problems in your oracle). We put equal weights there with $0$ weight everywhere else, request $x(w_0)$, modify the weight to $w[k]=|x(w_0)[k]|w_0[k]$ as above (it still has $m+1$ non-zero entries) call the oracle for the second time, and get a vector $x(w)$ (of length $n$) which has equal in absolute value entries in the weighted positions and some entries everywhere else. Let $M$ be the common absolute value of weighted entries. If all other entries are not greater than $M$ in absolute value, we are done: we have both a vector and a certificate for its optimality.
Otherwise let $|x(w)[q]|>M$ be the largest entry. Then we want to replace one of the weighted positions with $q$. Which one? The rule is that after replacement and doing the above procedure, we should get the vector whose entry in the replaced position is not greater in absolute value than the common absolute value of the now weighted positions. In other words, we solve the codimension 2 Chebyshev problem with $m$-dimensional subspace of $m+2$-dimensional space. I do it by the exhaustive choice ($m$ possibilities for the alternance positions). Note that the new candidate for the alternance will have the alternance value strictly greater than $M$, so we cannot do this replacement procedure forever. In finitely many iterations we are guaranteed to stop and get the true solution.
I should confess that I do not have a good theoretical upper bound on the number of iterations needed. However it practice on your suggested sample it works reasonably fast and experimenting with other functions in generic position corroborates this observation. The asymptote code is below. I cut some corners there because the code was experimental (so my oracle really sucks), but it still clearly shows that this approach is both viable and easy to implement. If you want to try it on Alberta Asymptote website, replace uuu<=100 with uuu<=2 (otherwise it will time out and that website does not show you the console output until the program terminates).
Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear :-)
srand(seconds());

int tot=0;

for(int uuu=1; uuu<=100; ++uuu)
{

int n=500; int m=9, md=m+1;
real[] x, w, mu;
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {x[k]=-pi+2*pi*k/(n-1); w[k]=0; mu[k]=1;}
x=sort(x);
int[] ind; int r=quotient(n-1,md);
for(int k=0;k<md;++k) {w[r*k]=1/md; ind[k]=r*k;}


real[] g(real x)
{
real[] u={exp(-x),1,exp(x),exp(-x)*sin(pi*x),sin(pi*x),exp(x)*sin(pi*x),
exp(-x)*sin(2*pi*sqrt(2)*x),sin(2*pi*sqrt(2)*x),exp(x)*sin(2*pi*sqrt(2)*x),};
return u;
}

real[] c; for(int k=0;k<m;++k) c[k]=2*unitrand()-1;
real f(real x)
{
real s=0; for(int k=0;k<m;++k) s+=c[k]*g(x)[k];
return floor(s+0.5);
}

real ff(real x, real[][] C)
{
real s=f(x); real[] gg=g(x);
for(int i=0;i<m;++i) s-=C[i][0]*gg[i];
return s;
}
real[][] A, B, C;

int MM=2000; real[] wold; real Mold=10000000; int mm;
for(mm=1;mm<=MM;++mm)
{


void work()
{

for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
{
A[i]=new real[]; 
real ss=0; for(int q=0;q<md;++q) ss+=w[ind[q]]*g(x[ind[q]])[i]*f(x[ind[q]]);
B[i]=new real[]{ss};
for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
{
real s=0; for(int q=0;q<md;++q) s+=w[ind[q]]*g(x[ind[q]])[i]*g(x[ind[q]])[j];
A[i][j]=s;
}

}
real[][] IA=inverse(A);
C=IA*B;
for(int k=0;k<5;++k) 
{
real[][] dC=IA*(B-A*C); C+=dC; 
}
real[][] ACB=A*C-B;
real s=0; for(int q=0;q<m;++q) s+=abs((ACB)[q][0]);
if(s>1/10^11) write(s);
}






real M=0, Mx=0, Mxx=0; int qq=0;




void setM()
{
M=0; Mx=0; Mxx=0; qq=0; 
real[] fff;
for(int q=0;q<n;++q) fff[q]=abs(ff(x[q],C));
for(int q=0;q<n;++q) 
if(Mx<fff[q]) {Mx=fff[q]; qq=q;}
for(int q=0;q<md;++q) Mxx=max(Mxx,fff[ind[q]]);
}



void update()
{
for(int q=0; q<md;++q) w[ind[q]]*=abs(ff(x[ind[q]],C));
real ww=sum(w);
for(int q=0;q<n;++q) w[q]/=ww;
}

work(); update(); work(); setM();


for(int k=0;k<m;++k) write(C[k][0],c[k], abs(C[k][0]-c[k]));
write("################");
for(int q=0;q<n;++q) if(w[q]>0){write(uuu, mm, q,x[q],ff(x[q],C), w[q]);}
write("***** "+string(Mx)+"  "+ string(Mold)+" ******");
write(qq);



Mold=min(Mx,Mold);

bool flag=false; for(int s=0;s<md;++s) if(ind[s]==qq) flag=true;
if(flag) break;

int ss=0; real MMM=100000000; int qqold=qq;
w[qqold]=1/md; for(int s=0;s<md;++s) w[ind[s]]=1/md; wold=copy(w); int[] indd=copy(ind);
bool flag=true;
for(int s=0; s<md && flag; ++s)
{
w[indd[s]]=0; ind[s]=qqold; work(); update(); work(); setM();
if(abs(ff(x[indd[s]],C))<=Mxx){ss=s; flag=false;}
w=copy(wold); ind=copy(indd);
}

w=copy(wold); ind=copy(indd);
w[ind[ss]]=0; ind[ss]=qqold; 

}

bool fflag=true;
for(int q=0;q<n;++q) if(abs(ff(x[q],C))>=0.5) fflag=false;
tot+=mm;
if(fflag) write(string(uuu)+" success! "+string(tot/uuu)); else {write("failure!"); pause();} 
}


very nice; thank you for putting so much effort in answering my question

@ManfredWeis You are most cordially welcome. Also that's what funny math. puzzles are for: putting effort into figuring them out. If you have some problems with implementation or something is still unsatisfactory, do not hesitate to ask more questions. The only request is that you should try to be as specific and to the point in your posts/comments as you can. Otherwise too much time is wasted on trying to get to the same page ;-)
